# I need to know the owner of a post, by using a foreign key referencing the table users from posts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projects`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

```
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine ='InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('jobtitle');
            $table->string('location');
            $table->string('jobtype');
            $table->string('jobdesc');
            $table->string('companyname');
            $table->string('howto');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('posts', function($table) {                                                                                              
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
         Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Post model

```
class Posts extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable =[
        'jobtitle', 
        'location',
        'jobtype',
        'jobdesc',
        'companyname',
        'howto',
        'user_id' 
    ];             

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 
    }
}
```

user model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Posts','user_id ');
}
```

Comment: i am new to laravel

Comment: Your error really isn't related to Laravel, it's an SQL error meaning that the posts.user_id you specified during the insert doesn't exist at users.id

Comment: Are you getting this error when trying to insert data into the table?

Comment: @ryantxr yes. true

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare a foreign key in the MySQL side, you have at least to create a `user_id` column (which you do have)  that will be used by Laravel as a foreign key.

To get user who created the post simply reference the relationship.

```
$owner = \App\Post::user->name; // get the user who created the post.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table definition is telling MySQL that it **must** have a value in `posts.user_id` and that value must exist in the `id` column in the users table. This is basic referential integrity.

Assuming that table users has the following :

```
| id | name     |
| 1  | Josie    |
| 2  | Jeff     |
```

Then the following insert into table `posts` will fail because table `users` does not have the corresponding user with id 5.

```
INSERT INTO posts
   (`jobtitle`,
    `location`,
    `jobtype`,
    `jobdesc`,
    `companyname`,
    `howto`,
    `user_id`) 
    VALUES (
    'manager',
    'some city',
    'cook',
    'cooks food',
    'Very good restaurants',
    'How we do things',
    5)
```

To solve this, you must determine the user **before** you attempt to insert into table `posts` and set the `user_id` column correctly.

Comment: i have an existing user who is in session, and wants to post, meaning there exists his id, which i am referencing, how do i determine the user, but someone can't create a post without logging in.

Comment: How would I know? You have not posted any code or said anything related to that. Perhaps that is in the session?

Comment: You can determine it using Auth::user()